# How can I allow everybody to read my Firebase Cloud Firestore

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I want to allow every User, even if he is not logged in, to read the datas of my database. But I want that only Users which are logged in and are "marked as a admin" can override this data...
Is there a way to do this? And is there a way to mark some Users as admin?

Btw I want to use swift if this is possible

Comment: Change the rules of firebase database so any user can read data with out authentication. you need to change this from firebase no need to change any thing at code side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For allowing only admins to edit, you will first have to give each user an 'admin' field in their user doc, which will only be set to True for Admins, then set the rules:

```
match /{document=**} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if request.auth != null && get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.admin == true
}
```

If you'd like some more help with documentation, Firestore has some nifty examples here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions